# What are the available obstacle avoidance algorithms in ROS?

Tags: ros, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

What are obstacle avoidance algorithms which available in ROS to implement unmanned ground vehicle (UGV)?

Hiba...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197162/what-are-the-available-obstacle-avoidance-algorithms-in-ros?/) by [hiba](https://answers.ros.org/users/20744/hiba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hiba,

See the [nav_core](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core#BaseLocalPlanner) documentation. Specifically have a look at BaseLocalPlanner interface.

Rick

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1